# Proving inverses with permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, inverse

Prove (if f and g are permutations) that $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$.

My teacher gave me the hint that it has something to do with identity mapping, but that doesn't help me at all.

Here's what I know, but am not sure how to use:
A permutation is a bijection, so it has an inverse that is also a bijection.
And I'm guessing you would use something like $(f \circ g)^{-1} \circ (f \circ g) = I_A$

Comment: Well, what does it mean for two functions to be inverse? There are two conditions, each involving the identity mapping. Check the conditions with the functions $f\circ g$ and $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: Almost. To show the inverse of $f\circ g$ is $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, you must show that $$(f\circ g)\circ(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})={\rm Id}=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ g)$$ Use associativity and some other rules to show these two facts.

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured it out. If you write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $u$ and $v$ are inverse, we show that $u\circ v$ and $v\circ u$ are the identity function.

In this instance then we want to show $f\circ g$ and $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ are inverses, or equivalently

$$(f\circ g)\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})={\rm Id}=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f\circ g).$$

To show this, use (generalized) associativity of function composition with the rule that both compositions $u\circ u^{-1}$ and $u^{-1}\circ u$ are $\rm Id$ for any function $u$.

Note that both conditions $u\circ v=\rm Id$ and $v\circ u=\rm Id$ must be met for $u$ and $v$ to be inverse functions; it is possible for pairs of non-bijective functions to satisfy one but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

start with
$(f \circ g)^{-1} \circ (f \circ g) = I_A$
As we know composition of function is Associative, ie. $(f \circ g)\circ h= f \circ (g\circ h)$
Applying this $=>((f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f) \circ g = I_A $
$=>((f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f) \circ g \circ g^{-1}  = I_A \circ g^{-1} $
$=>((f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f) \circ I_A  = g^{-1} $
$=>(f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f   = g^{-1} $
$=>(f \circ g)^{-1} \circ f \circ f^{-1}  = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} $
$=>(f \circ g)^{-1} \circ I_A  = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} $
$=>(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} $